# Grouping the data by (day) and then Join the 2 tables together in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

There are Two tables **licenses** and **organization**

**licenses table** contains 5 columns

```
oracle_apps       tableau      sab_bi      tririga     time_snapshot
0                  1            1           1          2017-06-13 08:12:02.640
0                  0            0           1          2017-06-13 09:12:02.640
0                  0            1           0          2017-06-13 11:52:02.640
0                  1            0           1          2017-06-14 09:12:02.640   
0                  0            1           0          2017-06-14 10:12:02.640
```

**organization table** has 2 columns

```
license_name                 license_count
oracle_                      5.0000000
tableau_                     1.0000000
sab_                         20.0000000 
tririga_                     10.0000000
```

So Output will an select query or pl SQL stored procedure that will contain the join of both the tables and it will show the **how many licenses are used in a day** (count)

### **Output:**

```
 oracle_apps    tableau    sab_bi    tririga    time_snapshot  oracle_    tableau_    sap_        tririga_  

 0              1          2         2          2017-06-13     5.0000000  1.0000000   20.0000000  10.0000000
 0              1          1         1          2017-06-14     5.0000000  1.0000000   20.0000000  10.0000000
```

**For Ex:** on *2017-06-13* total **5** licenses are used and individually *0,1,2,2*  i.e. sum(oracle_apps), sum(tableau), sum(sab_bi), sum(tririga)
and lly, on 2017-06-14 total 3 licenses are used i.e. **(0, 1, 1, 1)**

**That** thing was easy by using **group by to_char(time_snapshot, yyyy-mm-dd)** but I'm not able to join the tables and use row as a column  because in organization table the row will column in output and I know one way to do it using **PIVOT** but I'm confused how to get that in outcome and for each and every row the **license_name** values will be same i.e. ( 5.0000000 |  1.0000000 |   20.0000000
 |  10.0000000)

So is there a solution of **Grouping the data and Joining the table together?**

Comment: What have you tried ? If you have got errors, then there must be some query that has throw these errors, please append this query to the question.

Comment: Sorry bro the query i have used is only grouping the day .. Dont know how to join and use row as column can you plz provide me a full solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you pivot the data *before* joining:

```
select l.dte, l.oracle_apps, l.tableau, l.sab_bi, l.tririga,,
       o.oracle_, o.tableau_, o.sab_, o.tririga_
from (select trunc(l.time_snapshot) as dte,
             sum(l.oracle_apps) as oracle_apps,
             sum(l.tableau) as tableau,
             sum(l.sab_bi) as sab_bi,
             sum(l.tririga) as tririga
      from licenses l
      group by trunc(l.time_snapshot)
     ) l cross join
     (select sum(case when license_name = 'oracle_' then license_count else 0 end) as oracle_,
             sum(case when license_name = 'tableau_' then license_count else 0 end) as tableau_,
             sum(case when license_name = 'sab_' then license_count else 0 end) as sab_,
             sum(case when license_name = 'tririga_' then license_count else 0 end) as tririga_        
      from organization o
     ) o;
```

Aggregating on the individual tables seems safer to me (if `oracle_` appeared twice in the organization table, your *license* counts would be off).  In addition, the resulting queries may be faster because optimizations on a single table are usually easier than on multiple tables.

Comment: Well that was very well explained and optimized solution ... Thkx

Answer (score 2):

Use `CROSS JOIN`, `SUM`, `MAX`, `CASE..WHEN..THEN..` and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT trunc( l.time_snapshot) As time_snapshot,
       sum( l.oracle_apps ) As oracle_apps,
       sum( l.tableau ) As tableau,
       sum( l.sab_bi  ) As sab_bi,
       sum( l.tririga ) As tririga,
       max( CASE WHEN o.license_name = 'oracle_' THEN o.license_count END ) As oracle_,
       max( CASE WHEN o.license_name = 'tableau_' THEN o.license_count END ) As tableau_,
       max( CASE WHEN o.license_name = 'sab_' THEN o.license_count END ) As sab_,
       max( CASE WHEN o.license_name = 'tririga_' THEN o.license_count END ) As tririga_
FROM licenses l
CROSS JOIN organization o 
GROUP BY trunc( l.time_snapshot)
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/24b53/5

Comment: dude check your output again  cross join is applying to all 4 columns, that is why the value is becoming 4 times (sum) :)  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/24b53/5